# Email not sending - Mandic error or sender error

Tags: windows, email, exchange

The server is not sending e-mail. I will send you some info about the error and 2 photos of the screen.

E-mail Server Exchange 2007
The error send the information:The following organization rejected your message: SMTP-14.smtp.mandic.prv

Emails are being received normally.
Email is being send normally when inside the network of the company. But outside emails don't work.

Next i send the images of the error:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Question: Your Exchange does not send any outbound email or you have problem only just with the client's domain from attached screen shoots?

Unfortunately I do not know the portugese too much and do not understand the sentence from the header after *"Sender Address Rejected: Remetente..."*

From my experience it might be a problem on the receiver side. For instance, only trusted/approved senders can be able to send messages to this mailbox.

Did you check the tracking log on exchange and smtp gateway to check if email was relayed to internet? (I do not know how do you deal with email relay to internet).